# Bot reaction to SPECIFIC words

Tags: discord.py

I'm having an issue trying to get my bot to respond to specific words. For example, having the words 'her', 'he', 'shop', and 'hop' trigger the bot to say "test". I've added these to a loop/list however the bot triggers the response on ANY word that has a sequence of the above letters. If someone says 'theater' the bot will respond because "tHEater". Here is the code I tried:

```
triggers = ['he', 'she', 'hop', 'shop']

for word in triggers:
    if word in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("test")
        break
```

message.content == "she", etc does not work because this would only trigger on if someone ONLY typed 'she'.

What is happening? Is there a way for it to trigger on the specified sequence of letters?

Comment: Do `message.content.split(' ')` instead.

Comment: Like 3nws said, you could split the content on spaces and check with '==', or alternatively you could use regex and check for \bhe\b, \bshe\b, etc